# Disable redirect using custom routing filters in spring cloud gateway

Tags: redirect, routes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm modifying routes by setting `GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR` attribute in a custom filter.

```
exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, new URI("http://example.com"));
```

Works great but sends a redirect to the browser while I'd like to keep the original URL.

There is a similar issue discussed on [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/697) but the solution doesn't seem to work for me - resetting location in another filter makes browser redirect to that location i.e. the original URL, therefore making the whole routing recursive.

Spring cloud Greenwich.SR1

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Gateway never sends a redirect. If a response sends a redirect then gateway will proxy it.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is it possible to implement such a behaviour where the gateway detects 300 status codes in a response filter and performs redirect requests itself?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: I was facing this issue too - turns out I accidentally put an http url in the gateway when it should have been https. When gateway tried to hit the http url, the url sent back a 302 redirect to the browser and the browser redirected itself to the https url of the service rather than staying on the gateway url (at least that's what I think was happening lol).